# Oracle SQL Least Value Not Null

Tags: sql, oracle

Take the following query...

```
select
    trunc(dateX)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilX,
    trunc(dateY)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilY,
    least(trunc(dateX)-trunc(sysdate),trunc(dateY)-trunc(sysdate)) leastOfTheTwo
from myTable
```

If dateX or dateY is null then `least()` returns null.  I need to figure out how to have the `leastOfTheTwo` column return null only if both dateX and dateY are null, otherwise, I want the number.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE** To be clear, I cannot use `nvl` on the dates because they represent due dates. Meaning -1 (one day late), 0 (today), 1 (tomorrow), null (neither due dates ever set).

Comment: Yes, you can use NVL, just not by replacing null with 0.  See answer below.  You'll see that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    trunc(dateX)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilX,
    trunc(dateY)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilY,
    least(trunc(nvl(dateX, dateY))-trunc(sysdate),trunc(nvl(dateY, dateX))-trunc(sysdate)) leastOfTheTwo
from myTable
```

Comment: That did it, thanks, can't believe I didn't think of that, long day!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    trunc(dateX)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilX,
    trunc(dateY)-trunc(sysdate) daysTilY,
    least(nvl(trunc(dateX)-trunc(sysdate),0),nvl(trunc(dateY)-trunc(sysdate),0)) leastOfTheTwo
from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for me because it will make nulls appear as if they are all due today (0).  These represent due dates.  Meaning -1 (one day late), 0 (today), 1 (tomorrow), null (neither due dates ever set).  So I cannot change the numbers.  null means a due date was never set and needs to remain null.

Comment: No worries. I should have specified that initially.